Python try/catch in superclass for error handling, logic handling / error raised in subclass method
I can't seem to figure this out and it seems like something I should be able to do but I'm dumb and stupid so help me out internet.
I want to have superclass which requires an implementation of a method by it's inheritors, but ultimately has generic error handling which is to log the error and raise it. I prefer this method as I have a bunch of subclasses which use this object so updating the parent class is much less code changes and also just seems cleaner versus adding try/catch to every flavor of childClass I have
e.g.
class Super(object):
    logger = logging.GetLogger(__name__)

    def my_method(some_value):
        try:
            raise RuntimeError("my_method must be implemented")
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error("error raised: %s" % e)
            raise e

class childClass(Super):
    def my_method(some_value):
        # do some stuff, maybe an error gets raised         


I've implemented something like the above but I'm not seeing a log message being created

It looks like you have defined some functions not classes.

I don't understand why you would go through that try...raise...except...raise sequence only to raise an error.

woopsies, fixed that up. But essentially, I want to have consistent logging between all subclasses who use this method

@trincot The first raise, ensures the subclass has the my_method implemented, the second raise is if that subclass encounters an error during the execution of my_method we want it to be raised. It's psuedo ABC behavior

the straightfoward way to do this is to have child classes implement another method that is called by my_method, e.g. def _my_method, so in Super.my_method you call self._my_method() inside the try-except

childClass isn't extending Super so much as providing its implementation. If you choose to use inheritance, do as juanpa.arrivillaga suggested, and override a private method that does the real work of my_method.
class Super:
    logger = logging.GetLogger(__name__)

    def my_method(self, some_value):
        try:
            self._my_method(some_value)
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error("error raised: %s" % e)
            raise e

    def _my_method(self, some_value):
        raise NotImplementedError("_my_method must be implemented")


class childClass(Super):
    def _my_method(self, some_value):
        ...

Or, if Super only provides a logging context for arbitrary code, and have it be a context manager instead of using inheritance.
class LoggingContext:
    logger = logging.GetLogger(__name__)

    def __enter__(self):
        pass

    def __exit__(self, exc=None, *args):
        if exc is not None:
            self.logger.error("error raised: %s", exc)


class Child:
    def my_method(self, some_value):
        ...


c = Child()

with LoggingContext():
    c.my_method(foo)
        

The with statement "catches" any exception raised by Child.my_method and passes it to __exit__, which will log it and, by not returning True, have the with statement automatically reraise the error.

Of course you don't see any log: when you define 'childClass.mymethod()', the corresponding 'Super.mymethod()' gets overridden and never called. This is how inheritance works.
You probably want something like a logging decorator
